# Ansible not getting the value from list of dicts

Tags: python, xml, ansible

I need to:
- echo using debug the valueof the 'location'
- check if the 'location' contains specific word (whole word is fine)

based on this output generated by the [xml module](https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml):

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "apps": {
        "actions": {
            "ensure": "present",
            "namespaces": {},
            "xpath": "/server/application"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "count": 1,
        "matches": [
            {
                "application": {
                    "context-root": "helloworld",
                    "location": "text.zip",
                }
            }
        ],
        "msg": 1
    }
}
/
```

Comment: Have you tried something, or are you just assuming ansible will not get the value from list of dicts?

Comment: @shapsI have already tried, using apps.matches works fine, but can't get inside the application.  app.matches["application"] doesn't work

Comment: No, that won't work, as you said in the title, it's a list of dict, hence you will have to access it as `app.matches[0]['application']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- debug:
    var: item.application
  when: item.application.location == "foobar"
  with_items: "{{ apps.matches }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Register the variable in the task, then create a new task with a when clause.

```
  - Existing XML task
    xml: (skipping)
    register: myvar

  - Check for filename
    debug: var=item.application.location
    with_items: myvar.apps.matches
```

**EDIT:** From comments, since matches is an array, you may want to iterate through the array.